# Bug with configurate proxy vite

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi everyone i have issue with vite proxy.
In my app i created route `/games/:id` and if i press f5 on this page i been redirected on side api(where i get data)
I guess problem in my config proxy vite, but i cannot find any answers on that

Vite.config.js

```
    proxy: {
      "^/games(|/\\d+)$": {
        target: "https://www.giantbomb.com/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/games/, ""),
      },
      "/api": {
        target: "https://www.giantbomb.com/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
```

route.ts

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@/pages/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/games',
    name: 'games',
    component: () => import('@/pages/games/GamesPage.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/games/id',
    name: 'game-details',
    component: () => import('@/pages/games/GameDetails.vue')
  },
]
```

Comment: please post code, not pretty pictures of code - is the issue happening in development or production environment?

Comment: if i do /:games and pass there id everything okay, but in router /games/:id after f5 redirect on side api

code: 
vite.config.js
```
    proxy: {
      "^/games(|/\\d+)$": {
        target: "https://www.giantbomb.com/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/games/, ""),
      },
      "/api": {
        target: "https://www.giantbomb.com/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
```

Comment: my structure in pages
games/
GamePage.vue -> /games
GameDetails.vue  -> /games/:id

about "directory" i mean route

Comment: How is this /games supposed to work? A proxy doesn't make sense for it.

Comment: if i didnt put setting for route /games then after came on this route redirect on side api

Comment: If someone need more details link on github
https://github.com/VRez-web/pixel-point